# Are there "N + 1 problems" in "formfield_for_foreignkey()" in inline? (Django)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin

I overrided [**formfield_for_foreignkey()**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey) in inline to display **the combination text of "foreign key value" and "its parent value"** to **Django Admin** as shown below:

```py
# "admin.py"

class MyModelInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = MyModel

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        formfield = super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
        if db_field.name == "my_field":
            formfield.label_from_instance = lambda obj: f'{obj} ({obj.my_parent})'
        return formfield
```

Then, with **"print()"**, I checked how many time **"formfield_for_foreignkey()"** and **"if block"** in **"formfield_for_foreignkey()"** are called as shown below when opening the page:

```py
# "admin.py"

class MyModelInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = MyModel

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        formfield = super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
        
        print("formfield_for_foreignkey") # Called "3 times"

        if db_field.name == "my_field":

            print("if block") # Called "3 times"

            formfield.label_from_instance = lambda obj: f'{obj} ({obj.my_parent})'
        return formfield
```

As a result, **print("formfield_for_foreignkey")** is called **3 times** which means **"formfield_for_foreignkey()"** is called **3 times**.

And, **print("if block")** is called **3 times** which means **"if block"** in **"formfield_for_foreignkey()"** is called **3 times**.

#### My questions:

Is it **"N + 1 problem"** that:

- **"formfield_for_foreignkey()" itself** is called **3 times**?
- **"if block" itself** is called **3 times**?
- **"{obj}"** in **"if block"** is called **3 times**?
- **"{obj.my_parent}"** in **"if block"** is called **3 times**?